# Get data for specific logged in user from firestore database

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I am having this issue that I am not being able to get the name and surname of the current logged in user from the firestore database, for some reason the email of the current user is being displayed correctly but the name and surname are being displayed as "undefined undefined". I tried to debug it but with no success with this code that I have right now I am getting in console "User not found!".

```
  import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
  import EditIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Edit';
  import SettingsIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Settings';
  import HelpIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Help';
  import LogoutIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Logout';
  import '../../styles/familyTree.css';
  import profile_pic from '../../pages/familyTree/aaa.jpg';
  import { auth, db} from '../../../firebase';
  import Authentication from '../../../Authentication';
  import { doc, getDoc } from "firebase/firestore";

  function FamilyTree() {

    const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState();
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
    const menu = useRef();

    useEffect(() => {
      const handler = (e) => {
        if (!menu.current.contains(e.target)) {
          setOpen(false);
        }
      };

      document.addEventListener('mousedown', handler);
      return () => {
        document.removeEventListener('mousedown', handler);
      };
    });

    useEffect(() => {
      const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
        setCurrentUser(user);
      });
      return () => unsubscribe();
    }, []);

    async function getUserDoc() {
      if (!currentUser) {
        console.error("No current user!");
        return;
      }
      const userRef = doc(db, "users", currentUser.uid);
      const userDoc = await getDoc(userRef);
      if (userDoc.exists()) {
        const userData = userDoc.data();
        console.log("User data:", userData);
      } else {
        console.log("User not found!");
      }
    }
    
    useEffect(() => {
      if (currentUser) {
        getUserDoc();
      }
    }, [currentUser]);
    
    return (
      <div className="menu">
        <div className="menu-wrapper" ref={menu}>
          <div className="menu-main" onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}>
            <img src={profile_pic} alt="profile pic"></img>
          </div>

          <div className={`dropdown ${open ? 'active' : 'inactive'}`}>
            <h3>
            {currentUser ? `${currentUser.name} ${currentUser.surname}` : ''} <br/>
              <span>{currentUser ? currentUser.email : ''}</span>
            </h3>
            <ul>
              <DropdownItem href="./manageAccount" text="Edit Profile" icon={<EditIcon />} />
              <DropdownItem href="./manageAccount" text="Settings" icon={<SettingsIcon />} />
              <DropdownItem href="./manageAccount" text="Help" icon={<HelpIcon />} />
              <DropdownItem href="/" text="Logout" icon={<LogoutIcon />} onClick={() => {
                auth.signOut();
                console.log(`${currentUser.email} has been logged out`);
              }} />
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  function DropdownItem(props) {
    return (
      <li className="dropdown-items">
        {props.icon}
        <a href={props.href} className="items" onClick={props.onClick}> {props.text}</a>
      </li>
    );
  }

  export default Authentication(FamilyTree);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the code that showed the email correctly, replace `${currentUser.name} ${currentUser.surname}` with `${currentUser.displayName}` as there are no `name` and `surname` properties of the `User` object, it is combined into one - `displayName`
See the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.User#displayname) for more info on which properties are available (or just `console.log(currentUser)`
Hope this helps.

Comment: I needed to add something in other file as well but this helped, thanks.